# Why does not IMG tag work when I iterate over array of image links and show them with innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to know why does not this code show the images to me? I have checked the *view page source* and *firebug* after running the code. The *img* tags appear but they don't load the images provided in the array.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=0.8; maximum-scale=0.8;" />
<script>
var links = [
"1.jpg",
"2.jpg",
"3.jpg",
"4.jpg",
"5.jpg",
"6.jpg"
];
var images = "";
function showImages()
{
    for(i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
    {
        images += '<img id="myImage" href="'+links[i]+'">';
    }
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = images;
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.ph{border-style: solid;border-width: 5px;}
img.resize{max-width:100px;max-height:300px;margin:auto;}
#container{width: 500px;margin:auto; }
</style>
<title>Images</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"><script>showImages();</script></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do the images exist in that location ?

Comment: Yes, anyway, I had addressed to internet links. They exist, I have tested it. I have used another method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29488371/how-to-add-a-list-of-images-to-the-document-from-an-array-of-urls and it did work but I want to know what is wrong with the above code which fails to display images.

Comment: Firstly, you're creating elements with the same ID, that's wrong. Secondly, images don't have `href` property, they have a `src` property

Comment: @adeneo Thanks for pointing the same id problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image elements need a `src` instead of a `href` attribute.
So change

```
images += '<img id="myImage" href="'+links[i]+'">';
```

to

```
images += '<img id="myImage" src="'+links[i]+'">';
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ujxh2oha/)

Comment: doh! I might have lost my sight! :)