# Create a certain number of elements based on integer with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json file with an `items` category that lists items that are currently listed via an array. This item list is updated every few hours.

ex:

```
{
"items": [
    {
     "name": "Blueberry",
     "img": "website.com/blueberry.png"
    },
    {
     "name": "Raspberry",
     "img": "website.com/raspberry.png"
    }
         ]
}
```

Each item in the array is given an image and description. What I want to do is for every item, create an `<img src='(item image url)'>` element for the image that is listed inside the item, and create a `<p>` element for every item for the description that is listed.

Comment: have you tried something to get the Json Data

Comment: I have already gotten the Json data via the `getJSON` function in jquery. I'm just having trouble translating that data into HTML elements.

Comment: you can use the `document.createElement` on javascript

Comment: Thank you. How do I apply this to every item in the array?

Comment: look the answer i posted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a list of images to the document from an array of URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29488371/how-to-add-a-list-of-images-to-the-document-from-an-array-of-urls)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with JQuery with a for loop, and create the elements dynamically using the JQuery function `$(...)` (Tutorial [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp))

In the end, You'll probably end up with something like this:

```
// fetch the items from the url
$.getJSON("your url").then(function(response){

  //cycle through all the items in the array
  for(var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++){

    // create image
    var image = $('<img>').attr("src", response.items[i].img);
    // make sure to set the attribute using the "attr" function 
    //  to avoid Cross Site Scripting (see the link below)

    // create text element
    var text = $('<p>').text(response.items[i].name);

    // append the items to the container
    $("container element").append(image).append(text);
   }
});
```

[About Cross Site Scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Comment: @docyoda no problem!

Answer (score 0):

To dinamically create elements in Pure JavaScript you can use the `document.createElement`

```
var imagesContainer = document.createElement('div')

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

    var img = document.createElement('img'),
        p = document.createElement('p');

    img.setAttribute("src", array[i].img);

    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i].name));

    imagesContainer.appendChild(img);
    imagesContainer.appendChild(p);
}
```

i think is this you are looking for :)

Comment: I am getting this error in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'TextNode' of undefined`

Comment: sorry, i write wrong, is `createTextNode` and not `create.TextNode` @docyoda